# character type detection

Tags: jquery

Below is what I've already written and it's working fine:

```
var $remaining = $('#remaining'),
$messages = $remaining.next();

$('#message').keyup(function(){
var chars = this.value.length,
    messages = Math.ceil(chars / 160),
    remaining = messages * 160 - (chars % (messages * 160) || messages * 160);

$remaining.text(remaining + ' characters remaining');
$messages.text(messages + ' message(s)');
```

});
[This is the above code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/nkuBa/)

And now what I'm trying to do is :

```
var text_max_En = 100;
var text_max_utf8 = 200;
if   /*  what user has typed is English   */
{
   Do this
}
else if /*  what user has typed is in utf8 type*/
{
   Do that
}
```

In short :

`**If**` user has typed there in English then it should count up to 100 characters per message

`AND **if**` that's in urf8 type then it should count up to 200 ones.

Any solution?

Comment: Try to code DRY, makes your problem more visible.

Comment: What is `utf8 type`? Can you give an example?

Comment: Don't Repeat Yourself, but you updated your question nicely.

Comment: like an Asian language. An example could be Persian which is "fa" in character types.

Comment: @Andries I hope that helps find me the solution.

Comment: @John, your question is a bit confusing due by mixing a language with an encoding. Do you mean that you want to check if the characters are within the utf-8 (like ASCII) codepage and requires 8 bits or exceeds it requiring 16 bits or above? Maybe this link helps, to understand encodings: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html. (The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!))

Comment: yes, I meant utf8. The aim is to detect whether the user has typed in urf8 type or not. Am I clear enough about that ?

Comment: Next question: do you have a strong reason to give double the length of text for non-UTF8 entries?  Note that String.length accounts for the fact that unicode input is 2 bytes long.  E.g., if you run `alert('\uD800\uDC00'.length);`, the result will be 2, even though the input was 4 bytes long.  See for example, my really basic test fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ALdt/

Comment: In fact, the javascript specification (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf, page 29) says that all strings are composed of 16-bit characters.  If you're worried about 32-bit characters, look at example2 in the link I provided in my answer, and it will tell you how to check for that.

Comment: I checked that and am trying to do it. By the way, I don't have an absolute answer for your question.

Comment: The abridged version of that code is: if the value returned by charCodeAt is between 55296 and 56191, then you're dealing with the first part of a "two character" character.  If the return value is between 56320 and 57343, then it's the second part.  Anything less than 55296 is a single character.

Comment: Well I don't think I got 100% of your explanations but I appreciate the time and effort you are giving it :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [String.charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) to get the numeric value of any or all characters in a string.  If the value is > 127, then you're dealing with unicode values.

Since you're callback is `keyUp`, you can do this one at a time:

```
var str = $('#textarea').val();
var ascii = str.charCodeAt(str.length - 1) < 128;
```

(You can also just loop through the string length, but that's redundant, since you're acting one keystroke at a time.)

Comment: I'll try that,although implementing it wouldn't be easy for me. Thank you

Comment: I've totally messed that up. I applied your suggestion but not working. I suppose there is some syntax problem rather than a logical one. [check that here](http://jsfiddle.net/xqyWV/)

Comment: Do you mean the fiddle in my question or [This one](http://jsfiddle.net/kTukB/) ?

Comment: Try this.  Only one keyup function, in which you check the value and set the number to 160 or 80 based on that.  http://jsfiddle.net/xqyWV/263/

Comment: Thank you very very much ! Finally no use of `IF` ?

Comment: I used a shorthand for it in the line that sets number.  The `?:` terniary operator in that line translates to `if (this.value.charCodeAt(chars - 1) < 128) number = 160; else number = 80;`

Comment: I absolutely got that! And I just wonder how come you know these if you are learning Javascript !?

Comment: ?: is in C, C++, C#, ActionScript and JavaScript (and probably a few more places).  As for `charCodeAt`, I got that from wandering Mozilla developers network, looking at their String class.

Comment: I can't believe I've done c and c++ But I can't remember anything now due to NO USAGE of them. OK, Thank you anyway